# streaming hd video over internet

Tags: video-streaming

I will like to stream live hd video 24/7   But I don´t like to pay for a video stream server like http://www.viastreaming.com
What is the hardware and software you recommend for a 500 simultaneous users 
5 mbps it is enough
I have a dubt for simultaneous users and bandwidth needed

Thank you very much 
Have a nice day

Comment: Your question is difficult to read, you are a server sizing question which borders on being off-topic, and in 95% of the cases is too localized.  You might be able to ask a generic question about how to calculate the bandwidth required for streaming.

Answer (score 3):

> 5 mbps it is enough I have a dubt for simultaneous users and bandwidth needed

Are you joking?

Ok, here we go. HD video is BANDWIDTH INTENSIVE. 5mbit - yes, that is quite good. FOR ONE USER. That is ONE.

500 concurrent streams? 2500 mbit = 2.5 gigabit = 3 1gbit connections. Unless you distribute a LIVE feed, this is a LOT of problems on the storage backend. Even live it may not be doable on one server but need a cascade (main server distributes feed to distribution servers that each handle a maximum of X users).

With 2.5 gigabit you are going to run through 1 gigabyte of traffic every 4 seconds.

This is SERIOUS stuff. Not just a small server in a basement.

If you give up HD and go DVD quality, you CAN get things down - with prerecorded streams, not live - to around 2.5 megabit without TOO MUCH a video loss. That would half this bandwidth requirements. I Know that when I was transcoding videso to watch on my laptop I mostly went between 2-4 megabit - enough decent quality to watch when I travel ;) That was when discs were smaller.

So, you WILL pay. THis is something requiring a LOT of infrastructure and special build servers that can handle the load.